# Increase Size of InputForm in Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

I would like to set a variable equal to a copy n' pasted list, all within the Manipulate[] environment:

```
 Manipulate[list,{list,0}]
```

I would like to view and edit the elements of the list within the input field. The problem is the "white space" is not long enough to view the entire pasted list.

How can I make the input field larger, as if I were entering in a paragraph of text?

Comment: really hard to understand, since no simple MWE is given. Is this what you want? `Manipulate[list, {list, 0},ContentSize -> 1000]` ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8WqpD.png) (if you have a put complete example with some input, this will have eliminated the guess work)

Comment: Thanks - that's actually what I was looking for - just an expanded view within manipulate.

Comment: In addition to the answer given, you could also try `ContentSize->Automatic`. From help: `automatically size to fit`. There are number of other options as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
list2 = RandomReal[1, 200];
Manipulate[Length@list, {list, 0, ImageSize -> Full}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

With `list2` pasted into the InputField:

[image: Mathematica graphics]